# How to extract data from a JSON

Tags: html, json

I try for a couple of months to extract some data from this JSON :

```
    [["wrere","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",78,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"]
,
["hey men","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",76,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"]
,["rqwerqwer","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",75,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"]
,["roughouwehfwe","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",74,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"]
,["sadafsdfsadg","werewrwer",23,27,"profile_pic/twitter.png",73,27,23,"profile_pic/2.jpg"]
,
["hey \r\n","bogdan333",21,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",71,21,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg"]
,
["hey3","werewrwer",23,27,"profile_pic/twitter.png",67,27,23,"profile_pic/2.jpg"]
]
```

I try to use something like this:

```
var string="<form>"+
    "<div class='panel panel-white post panel-shadow user-post'>"+
    "<div class='post-heading'>"+
    "<div class='pull-left image'>"+
    "<img src='static/"+obj2[i][8]+"' class='img-circle avatar' alt='user profile image'>"+

    "</div>"+
    "<div class='pull-left meta'> "+
    "<div class='title h5'>"+
    "<a href='#'><b>"+obj2[i][1]+"</b></a> made a post."+
    "</div>"+
    "<h6 class='text-muted time'>1 minute ago</h6>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div> <div class='post-description'> "+
    "<p>"+obj2[i][0]+"</p>"+
    "<div class='stats'>"+
    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item'> "+
    "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>2</a> "+
    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item' id='show-comments'>"+
    "<i class='fa fa-share icon'></i>12</a>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div><div class='post-footer'>"+
    "<div class='input-group'> "+
    "<input class='form-control' placeholder='Add a comment' type='text'>"+
    "</div>     "+      
    "</div>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</form>" 


    //for(i in obj2){
    for(i=1;i<=7;i++){

  $('#load_data').append(string );

 //  }
 }
```

but the data that i get is just the first json array 7 times
[image: if you can look is the first array post repeting]

If someone can help me or if can give me a tutorial where I can look for more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, let's keep the concerns separate. HTML belongs with HTML not in the javascript so we'll move that out of the javascript. This will make your script cleaner.

Next, we will loop through your JSON object (which isn't really that much of an object), make a new post element based on the template and populate it.

```js
var posts = [
  ["wrere", "bogdan12", 31, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg", 78, 21, 31, "profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["hey men", "bogdan12", 31, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg", 76, 21, 31, "profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["rqwerqwer", "bogdan12", 31, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg", 75, 21, 31, "profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["roughouwehfwe", "bogdan12", 31, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg", 74, 21, 31, "profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["sadafsdfsadg", "werewrwer", 23, 27, "profile_pic/twitter.png", 73, 27, 23, "profile_pic/2.jpg"],
  ["hey \r\n", "bogdan333", 21, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg", 71, 21, 21, "profile_pic/poza3.jpg"],
  ["hey3", "werewrwer", 23, 27, "profile_pic/twitter.png", 67, 27, 23, "profile_pic/2.jpg"]
];

//Set Up the template
var s = $("#postTemplate")[0].innerHTML.trim();
var holder = document.createElement('div');
holder.innerHTML = s;
var template = holder.childNodes;

//Display out data
for(i = 0; i < posts.length; i++)
{
  var post = posts[i];
  //Clone Template
  var newItem = $(template).clone();

  //Populate it
  $(newItem).find("[data-field='profileImage']").attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + post[8]);
  $(newItem).find("[data-field='userName']").html(post[1]);
  $(newItem).find("[data-field='postDescription']").html(post[0]);
  //Append it
  $("#load_data").append(newItem);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load_data">
</div>
<!-- Template for our posts -->
<script type="text/template" id="postTemplate">
  <form>
    <div class='panel panel-white post panel-shadow user-post'>
      <div class='post-heading'>
        <div class='pull-left image'>
          <img src='static/' class='img-circle avatar' alt='user profile image' data-field="profileImage">
        </div>
        <div class='pull-left meta'>
          <div class='title h5'>
            <a href='#'><b data-field="userName"></b></a> made a post.
          </div>
          <h6 class='text-muted time'>1 minute ago</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='post-description'>
        <p data-field="postDescription"></p>
        <div class='stats'>
          <a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item'>
            <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>2
          </a>
          <a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item' id='show-comments'>
            <i class='fa fa-share icon'></i>12</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='post-footer'>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <input class='form-control' placeholder='Add a comment' type='text'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the new index everytime you add the string, the easiest way to do that is to put your string in a function that gets the index where you are and run the function with the right index.

```
function getString(i){
    return "<form>"+
    "<div class='panel panel-white post panel-shadow user-post'>"+
    "<div class='post-heading'>"+
    ... //the rest of your string
}

for(i=1;i<=7;i++){
    $('#load_data').append(getString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = [
  ["wrere","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",78,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["hey men","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",76,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["rqwerqwer","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",75,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["roughouwehfwe","bogdan12",31,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",74,21,31,"profile_pic/download.jpg"],
  ["sadafsdfsadg","werewrwer",23,27,"profile_pic/twitter.png",73,27,23,"profile_pic/2.jpg"],
  ["hey \r\n","bogdan333",21,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg",71,21,21,"profile_pic/poza3.jpg"],
  ["hey3","werewrwer",23,27,"profile_pic/twitter.png",67,27,23,"profile_pic/2.jpg"]
]

var template="<form>"+
    "<div class='panel panel-white post panel-shadow user-post'>"+
    "<div class='post-heading'>"+
    "<div class='pull-left image'>"+
    "<img src='static/DATA8' class='img-circle avatar' alt='user profile image'>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='pull-left meta'> "+
    "<div class='title h5'>"+
    "<a href='#'><b>DATA1</b></a> made a post."+
    "</div>"+
    "<h6 class='text-muted time'>1 minute ago</h6>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div> <div class='post-description'> "+
    "<p>DATA0</p>"+
    "<div class='stats'>"+
    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item'> "+
    "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up icon'></i>2</a> "+
    "<a href='#' class='btn btn-default stat-item' id='show-comments'>"+
    "<i class='fa fa-share icon'></i>12</a>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div><div class='post-footer'>"+
    "<div class='input-group'> "+
    "<input class='form-control' placeholder='Add a comment' type='text'>"+
    "</div>     "+      
    "</div>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</form>"

for(i=0;i<=obj.length;i++){
  var str = template.replace('DATA0', obj[i][0]).replace('DATA1', obj[i][1]).replace('DATA8', obj[i][8])
  $('#load_data').append(str)
}
```